# aligning controls in asp.net and css

Tags: html, asp.net, css

i have a webform app that i have desinged as seen in the image.
[image: vs designer]

Now here is the browser render for the same page.
[image: Broser output]

as you can see the output is completely misaligned. but the designer file i perfect.

the markup is too long to post here but i have two div one left and right which are alinged perfectly.

i use the following css tags

```
  .label, .textbox{
  width:150px;
  text-align:left;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  }
 .label, .dropdownlist{
 width:150px;
 text-align:left;
 float:left;
 display:block;
 }
 .label,.dropdownlist{

 text-align:left;
 float:left;
 display:block;
 margin-left: 23px;
  }
```

there are no other relevant that i can think of that can make such a misalgined output.
one more thing every control is nested withing a ul tag.

any and all help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Also paste your html please!

Comment: it is too long and big to paste.
but i will try to paste it.

Comment: @REZR.AMX one bit of advice don't change your css from the look of designer, open it in a browser and then write css rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be helpful to clean up your CSS, which is a little redundant.  The following is equivalent to your current CSS rules:

```
.label, .textbox, .dropdownlist
{
    width:150px;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}

.label,.dropdownlist
{
     margin-left: 23px;
}
```

This actually looks okay for what you're trying to accomplish (I think `display:inline-block` might be a more semantic choice, but since you're already floating to the left, I don't think it makes a difference).

However, this statement:

> one more thing every control is nested withing a ul tag

Concerns me a little bit.  It looks like whatever is wrapped around your controls is not being displayed in a 150px wide block-style format, which is causing the space between your elements to be dependent on the number of characters in the Label.

You could use your browser's developer tools to see what CSS rule is currently setting the width of the Label controls (or whatever is wrapped around the Label controls) to something that's less than 150 pixels.

It would helpful if you showed your HTML - or better yet, a small example on jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a framework like Bootstrap which will help you a lot. Take a look at bootstrap's [form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) and [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) frameworks.

Alternatively try this:

```
<div class="form-items">
    <label for="x">Label text</label>
    <input type="text" name="x" id="x" />    
</div>

<style>
    div.form-items label {
        width: 200px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
    div.form-items input {
        width: 300px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

See an example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wmv9/1/)

Comment: will give it a try, but is there no other way to improve my code without it?

Comment: There definitely is, try setting your labels to display block and with a width set and floated left. Then make sure each set of label and textbox is inside of a wrapper div.

Comment: Example added to my answer with a jsfiddle to test it too.